# Vim pattern to replace all instances of vspace

Tags: vim, latex, design-patterns

In technical papers typeset with latex we typically use a lot of "vspace" tricks to get the paper to lay out properly within the page limit.  Of course, when the font or number of columns changes,  they all break.  What is a good way to replace all instances of items like this:

```
\vspace{3.4mm}
\vspace{2in}
\vspace{-1.2in}
\vspace{-3mm}
```

with

```
\vspace{0mm}
```

using a vim pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%s/vspace{[^}]\+}/vspace{0mm}/g`

key:

- `%`: search for pattern on all lines in file.
- `vspace{[^}]\+}`: search for "vspace{1 or more of any character except `'}'`}"

Comment: Would it be worth changing this to `%s/vspace{[^}]\+}/vspace{0mm}/g` to prevent greedy matching to the last `}` in the line?

Comment: @PDug: As noted by you and others (@Randy Morris), the pattern should be modified to not be too greedy.  I updated my answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One solution that does not depend on vim is to define the following

```
\newcommand{\myvspace}[1]{\vspace{#1}}
```

then when you want to change it to 0mm you just replace this by

```
\newcommand{\myvspace}[1]{\vspace{0mm}}
```

Comment: The purpose of resetting them all to zero was to get the document to typeset reasonably so I can go back in and tweak them all manually again.  Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
:%s/\\vspace{.*}/\\vspace{0mm}/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
:%s#\\vspace{\zs.*\ze}#0mm#g
```

Does this command do the job?

Answer (score 0):

A few of the other answers here will be too greedy in the case there is another `}` on the same line after the target `}`.  The following should fix that:

```
:%s/vspace{\zs[^}]\+\ze}/0mm/g
```